# ConTeXt : background VS textbackground

Tags: floats, context

I was wondering why the background environment is announced to be deprecated (example [here](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/setupbackground)), and to should I use instead to create a background including floats, for example in this MWE. Thank you in advance,

```
\setupexternalfigures[location={local,default}]
\starttext
%% Is supposed to be deprecated but works better
\startbackground
  \input hawking
  \placefigure[here,center,none]{}{
    \externalfigure[cow.pdf]
  }
  \input hawking
\stopbackground
\page
\starttextbackground
  \input hawking
  \placefigure[here,center,none]{}{
    \externalfigure[cow.pdf]
  }
  \input hawking
\stoptextbackground
\stoptext
```

[image: background env]
[image: textbackground env]

Comment: Use `\setuptextbackground[location=always]`. Text backgrounds are more fine-grained and integrate better with MetaPost

Comment: @JairoA.delRio – You also need `\setupfloat[freeregion=no]` to enable the background behind the picture.

Comment: @DG' Oops, nice point. I missed that

Comment: You already see a reason why text background is better than background. Textbackground gives you the option to _not_ place the background behind the float (which could be a postponed float from a previous location), while background does not provide such a possibility

Comment: Thank you for the discussion !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an answer why the mechanisms were changed and `background` is considered obsolete, then I suggest you consult the mailing list. If you want to replicate the behaviour of `background`, then you simply need to add some setup options to `float` (especially `\setupfloat[freeregion=no]`) and `textbackground`:

```
\setupexternalfigures[location={local,default}]
\starttext
%% Is supposed to be deprecated but works better
\startbackground
  \input hawking
  \placefigure[here,center,none]{}{
    \externalfigure[cow.pdf]
  }
  \input hawking
\stopbackground
\page

\setuptextbackground
  [frame=off,
   location=always]
\setupfloat[freeregion=no]

\starttextbackground
  \input hawking
  \placefigure[here,center,none]{}{
    \externalfigure[cow.pdf]
  }
  \input hawking
\stoptextbackground

\stoptext
```

[image]